# Не работает скрипт jq

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Есть скрипт:

```
$(".show-more").click(function(){
    $(document).find(".more-card:not(:visible):lt(1)").slideToggle('fast',
        function() {
            if ($(document).find(".more-img:card(:visible)").length==0) {
                $(".show-more").css("display","none");
            }
        }
    );
})
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
more-card.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).slideToggle is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (more-card.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @   more-card.js:2
dispatch    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
```

Должен при нажатии на кнопку показывать следующую строчку.

В другом месте, похожий скрипт работает без проблем.
подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

```js
$(".show-more").click(function() {
  $(document).find(".more-card:not(:visible):lt(1)").slideToggle('fast',
    function() {
      if ($(document).find(".more-img:card(:visible)").length == 0) {
        $(".show-more").css("display", "none");
      }
    }
  );
})
```

```css
.more-card {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ********* -->
<div class="conteiner patrons-row-card">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="patrons-card">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <img src="../img/main_patrons_img_01.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="patrons-card-border">
              <h4>Русский Иллюзион</h4>
              <p class="patrons-card-p">г. Москва</p>
              <div class="row">
                <p><img src="../img/patrons_icon_rub.png" alt="">
                  <img src="../img/patrons_icon_star.png" alt="">
                  <span class="patrons-main-icon-text">> 500 000 руб.</span></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="patrons-card">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <img src="../img/main_patrons_img_02.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="patrons-card-border">
              <h4>Русский страховой центр</h4>
              <p class="patrons-card-p">г. Москва</p>
              <div class="row">
                <p><img src="../img/patrons_icon_rub.png" alt="">
                  <img src="../img/patrons_icon_cub.png" alt="">
                  <img src="../img/patrons_icon_star.png" alt="">
                  <span class="patrons-main-icon-text">> 1 000 000 руб.</span></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ********* -->
<div class="conteiner patrons-row-card more-card">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="patrons-card">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <img src="../img/main_patrons_img_03.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="patrons-card-border">
              <h4>Сибирская пиротехника</h4>
              <p class="patrons-card-p">г. Екатеренбург</p>
              <div class="row">
                <p><img src="../img/patrons_icon_rub.png" alt="">
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="patrons-card">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <img src="../img/main_patrons_img_04.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="patrons-card-border">
              <h4>Русская химическая компания</h4>
              <p class="patrons-card-p">г. Нижний Новгород</p>
              <div class="row">
                <p><img src="../img/patrons_icon_rub.png" alt="">
                  <img src="../img/patrons_icon_star.png" alt="">
                  <span class="patrons-main-icon-text">> 1 000 000 руб.</span></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="patrons-button"><a class="button-1 show-more" href="#" role="button">Показать еще</a></div>
```

Comment: _в чем может быть проблема?_ - в чем угодно. Без [mcve] можно только гадать, что у тебя за код и есть ли вообще ошибка.

Comment: извиняюсь. код добавил

Comment: @codename0082016, если вставляешь сниппет, сделай его рабочим, как минимум надо jquery подключить

Comment: это как подключить?

Comment: Сам по себе предоставленный код работает так, как и ожидается (работающий сниппет это демонстрирует). Есть ли еще какие-то ошибки в консоли?

Comment: @codename0082016, поправил сниппет

Comment: Похоже, "В другом месте" неверно подключен jquery

Comment: Других ошибок в консоли нет. jquery подключен так же как и на этой странице.

Comment: @ВячеславГурьянов, ищи чем отличаются твои две страницы. Какие скрипты когда подключены. Как можешь убедиться сниппет полностью рабочий, следовательно проблема в окружении.